# Kony Studio App is not running in iPhone

Tags: ios, temenos-quantum

I am an iOS developer & currently developing an app in Kony studio. App is working fine in simulator but when I am trying to install app in iOS device (iPhone5) , I am getting splash screen & after that a white screen appears. In Xcode log I found following

**DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C91C65C3-3B94-4A4C-B03A-3EEE0E608C9E/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies**

All apps developed in Kony studio are showing same behavior but I am able to run all Native apps develop in Xcode in iPhone.

Did any one face this issue earlier? Any help or Idea would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It was my mistake.

I did not added my bundleID in Kony studio & only added in Exported iOS project. Later I resolved this issue. Apologizes for late reply.